# Performance of an Order by Clause

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

Please could someone help me understand how an Order By clause can be sped up?

I have done a lot of research but can't seem to find an answer.

I have a table with 1 million rows of test data and the following query will take between 20-30 seconds to load:

```
SELECT f.f_id, f.type, f.s_id, f.story_name, f.new_story, f.share_id, f.photo_template, f.num_media, f.num_products, f.original_language, f.original_language_name,
f.feed_photo, f.feed_photo_type, f.feed_photo_length, f.feed_photo_video,
f.feed_photo2, f.feed_photo2_type, f.feed_photo2_length, f.feed_photo2_video,
f.feed_photo3, f.feed_photo3_type, f.feed_photo3_length, f.feed_photo3_video,
f.feed_photo4, f.feed_photo4_type, f.feed_photo4_length, f.feed_photo4_video,
f.feed_photo5, f.feed_photo5_type, f.feed_photo5_length, f.feed_photo5_video,
f.feed_photo6, f.feed_photo6_type, f.feed_photo6_length, f.feed_photo6_video,
f.background_photo, f.font_colour, f.hashtag_colour, f.at_name_colour,
f.title, f.content, f.num_likes, f.num_comments, f.hashtag, f.shared_with, f.created_by, f.date_order, f.date_published,
u.u_id, u.forename, u.surname, u.profile_photo, u.username, u.staff_member, u.brand_ambassador, u.last_signed_in, u.deleted,
s.s_id AS seller_id, s.name AS seller_name, s.logo AS seller_logo,
g.g_id AS group_id, g.name AS group_name, g.type AS group_type
FROM feed AS f
INNER JOIN users AS u ON u.u_id = f.created_by
LEFT JOIN sellers AS s ON s.s_id = f.seller_id
LEFT JOIN groups AS g ON g.g_id = f.group_id
WHERE f.published = 1 AND f.deleted = 0 AND f.shared_with = 1
OR f.published = 1 AND f.deleted = 0 AND f.shared_with = 2 AND g.type = 0
OR f.published = 1 AND f.deleted = 0 AND f.shared_with = 2 AND f.group_id IN (5, 4)
OR f.published = 1 AND f.deleted = 0 AND f.shared_with = 3 AND f.created_by = 1
GROUP BY f.f_id
ORDER BY f.date_order DESC
LIMIT 0, 20
```

However, if I remove the `ORDER BY f.date_order DESC` it will load instantly.

I have tried adding an index for the date_order.

Why would it take 20-30 seconds to load with the date_order column but load instantly without it?

Below is the Explain of the query:
[image: Explain]

Thank you

---

UPDATE:
I have since changed my query to use the latest ID loaded on the previous page:

```
SELECT f.f_id, f.type, f.s_id, f.story_name, f.new_story, f.share_id, f.photo_template, f.num_media, f.num_products, f.original_language, f.original_language_name,
f.feed_photo, f.feed_photo_type, f.feed_photo_length, f.feed_photo_video,
f.feed_photo2, f.feed_photo2_type, f.feed_photo2_length, f.feed_photo2_video,
f.feed_photo3, f.feed_photo3_type, f.feed_photo3_length, f.feed_photo3_video,
f.feed_photo4, f.feed_photo4_type, f.feed_photo4_length, f.feed_photo4_video,
f.feed_photo5, f.feed_photo5_type, f.feed_photo5_length, f.feed_photo5_video,
f.feed_photo6, f.feed_photo6_type, f.feed_photo6_length, f.feed_photo6_video,
f.background_photo, f.font_colour, f.hashtag_colour, f.at_name_colour,
f.title, f.content, f.num_likes, f.num_comments, f.hashtag, f.shared_with, f.created_by, f.date_order, f.date_published,
f.poll_date_end, f.poll_choice1_val, f.poll_choice1_score, f.poll_choice2_val, f.poll_choice2_score, f.poll_choice3_val, f.poll_choice3_score, f.poll_choice4_val, f.poll_choice4_score, f.poll_choice5_val, f.poll_choice5_score, f.poll_choice6_val, f.poll_choice6_score, f.poll_choice7_val, f.poll_choice7_score, f.poll_choice8_val, f.poll_choice8_score, f.poll_choice9_val, f.poll_choice9_score, f.poll_choice10_val, f.poll_choice10_score,
u.u_id, u.forename, u.surname, u.profile_photo, u.username, u.staff_member, u.brand_ambassador, u.last_signed_in, u.deleted,
s.s_id AS seller_id, s.name AS seller_name, s.logo AS seller_logo,
g.g_id AS group_id, g.name AS group_name, g.type AS group_type
FROM feed AS f
INNER JOIN users AS u ON u.u_id = f.created_by
LEFT JOIN sellers AS s ON s.s_id = f.seller_id
LEFT JOIN groups AS g ON g.g_id = f.group_id
WHERE f.published = 1 AND f.deleted = 0 AND f.shared_with = 1 AND f.f_id >= 1802859 AND f.f_id <= 1802869
OR f.published = 1 AND f.deleted = 0 AND f.shared_with = 2 AND g.type = 0 AND f.f_id >= 1802859 AND f.f_id <= 1802869
OR f.published = 1 AND f.deleted = 0 AND f.shared_with = 2 AND f.group_id IN (5, 4) AND f.f_id >= 1802859 AND f.f_id <= 1802869
OR f.published = 1 AND f.deleted = 0 AND f.shared_with = 3 AND f.created_by = 1 AND f.f_id >= 1802859 AND f.f_id <= 1802869
ORDER BY f.date_order DESC, f.f_id DESC
LIMIT 11
```

and I have removed the group by as suggested.

It now loads in 0.3 seconds however as soon as I add `AND u.brand_ambassador = 1` to the where clause (which is a requirement for me depending on which view the user chooses) it jumps to 5-6 seconds.

This query takes 0.3 seconds:

```
SELECT f.f_id
FROM feed AS f
INNER JOIN users AS u ON u.u_id = f.created_by
LEFT JOIN sellers AS s ON s.s_id = f.seller_id
LEFT JOIN groups AS g ON g.g_id = f.group_id
WHERE f.date_order < '2018-03-21 15:41:03' AND f.published = 1 AND f.deleted = 0 AND f.shared_with = 1 AND u.brand_ambassador = 1
OR f.date_order < '2018-03-21 15:41:03' AND f.published = 1 AND f.deleted = 0 
AND f.shared_with = 2 AND g.type = 0 AND u.brand_ambassador = 1
OR f.date_order < '2018-03-21 15:41:03' AND f.published = 1 AND f.deleted = 0 
AND f.shared_with = 2 AND f.group_id IN (5, 4) AND u.brand_ambassador = 1
ORDER BY f.date_order DESC, f.f_id DESC
LIMIT 10, 1
```

The following query takes 5-6 seconds:

```
SELECT f.f_id
FROM feed AS f
INNER JOIN users AS u ON u.u_id = f.created_by
LEFT JOIN sellers AS s ON s.s_id = f.seller_id
LEFT JOIN groups AS g ON g.g_id = f.group_id
WHERE f.date_order < '2018-03-21 15:41:03' AND f.published = 1 AND f.deleted = 0 AND f.shared_with = 1 AND u.brand_ambassador = 1
OR f.date_order < '2018-03-21 15:41:03' AND f.published = 1 AND f.deleted = 0 AND f.shared_with = 2 AND g.type = 0 AND u.brand_ambassador = 1
OR f.date_order < '2018-03-21 15:41:03' AND f.published = 1 AND f.deleted = 0 AND f.shared_with = 2 AND f.group_id IN (5, 4) AND u.brand_ambassador = 1
ORDER BY f.date_order DESC, f.f_id DESC
LIMIT 10, 1
```

Below is the explain for the query:
[image: Explain 2]

Am I correct in thinking that users table isn't using the index on the brand_ambassador column?

I have tried using FORCE INDEX but can't seem to get it working with a joined table.

---

UPDATE:
As suggested by Solarflare removing the GROUP BY from the original query did the trick.

I now face a new problem.

When I change the last line of the where clause from `f.created_by = 1` to `f.created_by = 2` it goes back to taking 45 seconds to load.

Please see the explains below:

Query 1 (f.created_by = 1):
[image: Explain 1]

Query 2 (f.created_by = 2):
[image]

The million of test records I added are pretty much all created by user 1 which presumably has something to do with it.

Comment: Have you looked at the explain plan? The reason it comes back fast without order by is because of the limit. Since there is no order, it just returns the first 20 records. If you have an order by in there, it needs to scan the whole result set and sort it and then give you the first 20 records. Just because it returns fast without order by doesn't mean that order by is the issue. Look at the explain plan to see where you can improve performance.

Comment: @clinomaniac Thank you for your reply. I have added the explain extended to my question. I don't really understand how it helps me though. What am I looking for? I have tried a composite index on the 5 possible keys it shows with no joy.

Comment: How many rows do you get without limit? Also, remove the `GROUP BY f.f_id` (if you need it to get distinct result, we can find a better way to do it (as doing it this way is not valid sql), but it looks like all your joins are done using full primary keys (but you shoudl check that), so it should not affect your outcome, but maybe execution speed).

Comment: @Solarflare Please see my update as I have changed my query. The new query without the AND f.f_id >= ? and without the limit as suggested returns 41,608 pages (so about 1,248,240 rows). And thank you I have removed the group id and it took 1/2 a second off the load time (I needed it originally but since have no use for it and forgot about it). I should be using primary keys shouldn't I? I haven't ever tried anything with foreign keys, is this what you are suggesting? The u.u_id, s.s_id and g.g_id are primary keys but f.created_by, f.seller_id and f.group_id are just normal columns.

Comment: Your primary keys are fine. They were only relevant for deciding if `group by` had an effect on the result or not. Without `group by`, your original query still takes 20s minus 0.5s? It should be pretty comparable to your last query, just with `f.date_order < '2100-01-01'` (which probably also takes about 0.3s?), and is what I would expect if your query without limit will give basically all rows in the table (1,248,240 out of about a million). So a similar question: how many rows with `u.brand_ambassador = 1` (and no limit)? How many users with `u.brand_ambassador = 1`?

Comment: A side note: unless `order_date` is unique, for pagination, you need to include the id as a second condition (otherwise, if 2 rows have the same `order_date`, and your page ends with the first of it, the next page will skip the second row). Also: the last 2 queries are identical (unless I missed something), I assume the 0.3s query should not have `AND u.brand_ambassador = 1`? The first query in the "update" part can't be used for pagination (by order_date) because of the `AND f.f_id >= 1802859 AND f.f_id <= 1802869`, it limits your result to these 11 rows, no matter what order_date they have.

Comment: @Solarflare Thank you for all your help with this. When I ran the queries again and removed the group by on the original query it worked perfectly!!!

Comment: @Solarflare I spoke too soon. If I change the last line of the where clause to `f.created_by = 2` instead of `f.created_by = 1` then it takes 45 seconds to load. The millions of test posts I created are all by user 1 so presumably it has to look through lots of rows before it finds posts by user 2. Any ideas?

Comment: @Solarflare I have added the explains for both queries to the bottom of my question.

Comment: @Solarflare Ignore me. I used FORCE INDEX on the feed table and in the 3 joined tables and it is running quicker than ever now.